# MediaPlayer onCompletion is not being called accurately

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, wav

In my app i have created an audio player (only WAV files) using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) API.
But the player doesn't give callback to onCompletion Listener everytime. Sometimes it gives callback but not everytime. I am doing some audio processing on wav file , like insertion and overwriting.

Is it because any missing in audio header?
Why it doesn't give callback when the playback is completed?

Comment: In case the app is on sleep. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813486/oncompletion-isnt-being-called-when-i-would-expect-it-to/60911323#60911323

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the headers of file is set correctly. If somethings in header is missing `callback` to the `onCompletion` may not occur.

If mediaplayer is playing a `.wav` file, seeking may happen correctly but a jerking will be there . So when the playingback completes there will be a differecnce of 0-1000 ms between total duration of file and `onCompletion` respectively. So if such a situation comes you should guess that as onColmpletion and do what you wanted. Thats a bit tricky way to get the `onCompletion`.

I faced the same problem while playing a `.wav` file with the mediaplayer. This is not a good way to solve this issue, but I tackled the same problem like this when i was having the same situation. Hope this will help you too in some ways.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have to call setOnCompletionListener AFTER calling start().
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555480/1860130

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the MediaPlayer is not a local(temporal) variable.  Since the local variable will be collected by GC. In that case, the onCompletion will have no chance to be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the onCompletion() function called you should disable looping with a call mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

Answer (score 0):

You're using the correct Method but have you passed any code in the 
**"// do some tasks here when playback completes " AREA**.

If not then the callback wont make any sense.

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playback Completes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This method will pop a Toast on completion of playback.

Answer (score 0):

Return **true** to OnErrorListner method on MediaPlayer

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation
    switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            Log.e("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            Log.e("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            Log.e("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use a sleep method once recording is completed. 
Also use; .prepare() before the placeback occurs , to avoid crashes.